# How to open chrome in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch chrome with `Selenium Webdriver` and used the following code:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                   "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Chrome browser opens but is not proceeding further. What could be the reason for the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest versions of ChromeDriver.

**Source|**

```
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

Comment: I think zip file is available for 32 bit but I am using 64 bit machine. Anyway I downloaded still getting the same error

Comment: @Shyamala Seems there is no ChromeDriver for Win-64 bit as of now. [Not sure, might be Win-32 bit works]

Comment: Have you tried the solution I gave for selecting checkbox? Try my use case rather than Thread.sleep()

Comment: Ya it worked.....But now for chrome I downloaded and mentioned that path as follows:System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/chromedriver.exe"); WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); driver.get("yahoo.com"); But the chrome is now opened and typing as data; and shows the following error Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 21321 and the port number changes every time

Comment: Try 2.9 instead of 2.4 since u r using latest chrome browser

Comment: Tried still the same....Can u please help me out as I am facing this issue for a long time

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly starting up the driver

`webdriver.chrome.driver` is supposed to be the path to the **driver** that you've downloaded and **not** Chrome's **physical** location.

Comment: Ok I have now downloaded and given the path as follows: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");  But the chrome is now opened and typing as data; and shows the following error Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 21321 and the port number changes every time

Comment: Well two things a) the port number is going to change, and b) that isn't the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download chrome driver file from this link and than import its JAR to the package in eclipse.

[Download the link from here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Then you will have to import it in your program.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

and than make a driver instance

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Download the external JAR of chrome

In eclipse :: right click on the respective package(in the package explorer) and click on the properties. Go to Java build path and add external jars. Now add the jar file of chrome . and than follow the steps i wrote in the ans which was to import the chrome driver and creating an instance

Follow these steps in the photograph.
1)[image]

select your file from here and right click
[image]

Comment: But when I download from this link and extract, only exe file is there

Comment: alternatively , you can also download it from here , http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumchromedriver20a4jar.htm

Comment: OK I downloaded and added as external jar.....System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"); and getting the error as follows [4236:2696:0220/181910:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[4236:2696:0220/181910:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Comment: In eclipse :: right click on the respective package(in the package explorer) and click on the properties. Go to Java build path and add external jars. Now add the jar file of chrome . and than follow the steps i wrote in the ans which was to import the chrome driver and creating an instance.

Comment: so it opens the chrome window now ??  so whats the next error ? what exactly happens ?  btw i updated my ans with screen shots please have a look if you havent yet.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet shows how you can open chrome browser using selenium webdriver.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Creating a driver object referencing WebDriver interface
        WebDriver driver;
        
        //Setting the webdriver.chrome.driver property to its executable's location
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/lib/chromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
    
        //Instantiating driver object
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        //Using get() method to open a webpage
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        
        //Closing the browser
        driver.quit();
 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your browser settings first. Try below-mentioned code if it helps:

```
public void setup ()    
{          
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\**PATH**\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
```

You'll need to import files by hovering on error lines.